# passing data to web page (QWebView)

Tags: json, qt, graph, web, pyside

I'm writing a UI for a client that parses some very nested JSON data. This UI is in PySide and I'd like to include some visualization of the data as well. I've recently come across QWebView and this seems like a great way to quickly embed 'stunning' charts into my UI that can potentially also be configured.

So the question is, how can I send 'signals' and data to the page? The one approach that would work is to manually create the page as a temp file and have the webview browse to that, but I think there should be a better way. Is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for [QWebFrame::addToJavaScriptWindowObject()](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#addToJavaScriptWindowObject). With that method, you can export QObjects to JavaScript. These objects can have signals you can connect to in JS, and you can also use properties or methods with return values to obtain some data.

See https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit-bridge.html for a complete overview on how the C++<->JS bridge works.

Comment: Thanks. I had solved my issue (rogue quote), but this link is great to avoid any further pitfalls. Thank you very much :)